# prisma error: Could not connect to server at http://localhost:4466

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm having trouble with deploying prisma.

The steps I've taken are the following:

1. create a new folder
2. run `prisma init`
3. select postgresql and fill in the required information.
4. complete the installation

Now when i got to use `docker-compose up -d` it creates the container and its running but when i go to deploy prisma, `prisma deploy`, i get the following error:

`Could not connect to server at http://localhost:4466.Please check if your server is running.`

is there any advice or documentation out there that can tell me why this is happening and how to run it properly?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: I was using Mac

Comment: Can you add the logs from docker-compose ?

Answer (score 4):

To me was a solution to change in prisma.yml http://localhost:4466 to endpoint with docker ip - http://192.168.99.100:4466

Also, this could be helpful if the problem is in apisecret https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/4483 - here

Answer (score 1):

docker is taking some time to startserver so please try again after some time it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that i deployed the project without setting `ssl: true` in the yml file. After that everything worked fine